# How to add QBFC as a dependency in visual studio

Tags: windows-installer, qbfc

I made a program that connects to QuickBooks to automate a task.
And it relies on QBFC13 so how can I make sure that QBFC13 is installed before installing my program.
Or is there a way to install it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with QBFC13 but why not use WiX and [WiX Bootstrapper](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/) to build your installs and chain them together?

I just looked up this product and it [looks like Intuit builds merge modules (MSM) for just your scenario](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/go-live/redistributing-sdk-components-with-your-application). After installer their SDK I would find the specific merge module and then include that in your install.